# how do i download and install imagemagick for os x el capitan?

Tags: imagemagick

so i went here:  https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

and download ImageMagick.tar.gz

tried to unpack the distribution with this command:
`tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz`

and got this error: 

`~ $ tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'ImageMagick.tar.gz'`

can anybody please help me get through this

Comment: The question is off topic as it belongs on [su] but... it's likely corrupted. Redownload and try again.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I forgot to reply back but yes I did work Thank you I appreciate the time for answering my question and getting back to me if I solved it

Answer (score 4):

Do yourself a favour if you want to install non-Apple packages and install a package manager such as **homebrew** which is a matter of copying and pasting a single line from the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh).

Then you can find any packages you want with:

```
brew search imagemagick
```

and install them and build them with

```
brew install imagemagick
```

However, *before* you do that... check if you want any specific features, such as HDR or EXR support, by running:

```
brew options imagemagick
```

**Sample Options**

```
--with-fftw
    Compile with FFTW support
--with-fontconfig
    Build with fontconfig support
--with-ghostscript
    Build with ghostscript support
--with-hdri
    Compile with HDRI support
--with-liblqr
    Build with liblqr support
--with-librsvg
    Build with librsvg support
--with-libwmf
    Build with libwmf support
--with-little-cms
    Build with little-cms support
--with-little-cms2
    Build with little-cms2 support
--with-opencl
    Compile with OpenCL support
--with-openexr
    Build with openexr support
--with-openjpeg
    Build with openjpeg support
--with-openmp
    Compile with OpenMP support
--with-pango
    Build with pango support
--with-perl
    Compile with PerlMagick
--with-quantum-depth-16
    Compile with a quantum depth of 16 bit
--with-quantum-depth-32
    Compile with a quantum depth of 32 bit
--with-quantum-depth-8
    Compile with a quantum depth of 8 bit
--with-webp
    Build with webp support
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
--with-zero-configuration
    Disables depending on XML configuration files
--without-freetype
    Build without freetype support
--without-jpeg
    Build without jpeg support
--without-libpng
    Build without libpng support
--without-libtiff
    Build without libtiff support
--without-magick-plus-plus
    disable build/install of Magick++
--without-modules
    Disable support for dynamically loadable modules
--without-threads
    Disable threads support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Then you can install them with a command such as:

```
brew install imagemagick --with-openexr --with-hdri
```

---

Later you can remove them with

```
brew rm imagemagick
```

and update all installed packages with

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: @AamirMahmood Yes, I am aware thank you. I'm afraid things change and it is not possible to go around updating all old answers.

Comment: I totally understand, just added this comment for other users. I came to this answer many times over last two days and when I find out that this feature is not working anymore i thought if I knew that from first time i would have looked for some alternate :)